# How can I pass string with space on JQuery load function

Tags: jquery

Hi here is the code: I want to pass variable that contains a string value with space.

here value for $companyname is "ABC Company Ltd."

```
<a href="bill.php?company=<?php echo $companyname; ?>" 
       onclick="jQuery('#bill').load('bill.php?company=<?php echo $companyname; ?>').dialog('open');  return false">update</a>
```

The bellow is not working:

```
<a href="bill.php?company=<?php echo $companyname; ?>" 
       onclick="jQuery('#bill').load('bill.php?company=ABC Company Ltd.').dialog('open');  return false">update</a>
```

But this one is working:

```
<a href="bill.php?company=<?php echo $companyname; ?>" 
       onclick="jQuery('#bill').load('bill.php?company=ABC%20Company%20Ltd.').dialog('open');  return false">update</a>
```

any help

Comment: Don't add javascript inline. HTML belongs in .html files, CSS belongs in .css files, and JS belongs in .js files.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urlencode($companyname)`](http://php.net/urlencode) to get a string suitable to be appended to a URL:

```
<a href="bill.php?company=<?php echo urlencode($companyname); ?>" 
       onclick="jQuery('#bill').load('bill.php?company=<?php echo urlencode($companyname); ?>').dialog('open');  return false">update</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a data argument to `load`.

```
jQuery('#bill').load('bill.php', { "company":"ABC Company Ltd." });
```